# How to retrieve both value & currency type from currency type attribute

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm

In MS Dynamics CRM 2013 I am trying to get the value & currency type from a currency type attribute using LINQ.

By this code I can only get the value.

actualvalue = (Money)opportunity.GetAttributeValue("actualvalue")

Can anyone suggest how to get the currency associated with this attribute, I need to use LINQ only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currency is stored inside the `transactioncurrencyid` field. It's a lookup so by code is an `EntityReference`.

```
var currencyRef = (EntityReference)opportunity.GetAttributeValue("transactioncurrencyid");
```

after you can retrieve the currency details using the `Id` property (so will be like `currencyRef.Id`)

Comment: Thanks a lot... I have changed it a bit: 

    actualCurrency = opportunity.Contains("transactioncurrencyid") ? ((EntityReference)opportunity["transactioncurrencyid"]).Name : string.Empty

Answer (score 0):

Get and Set Currency(Money) using `C#`

Get:

```
var moneyValue = ((Money)item.Attributes[attributeName]).Value;
```

Set:

```
newSalesOrder[attributeName] = new Money((decimal)moneyValue);
```